# Django 3.0 missing positional argument in db converter

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Setting up a website using Django 3.0.6, django-cms 3.7.2, djangocms-blog 1.1.1, PostgreSQL 12, Apache 2.4.29, Ubuntu 18.04. All was going well until I attempted to create my first blog post. The attempt apparently succeeded (and there is a row in djangocms_blog_post,) but from the point I hit the 'save' button onward, every operation that hits the blog (or, oddly, my main menu) results in a TypeError: "from_db_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'."
Per the error page, the culprit is /lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in function apply_converters, line 1095:

```
value = converter(value, expression, connection)
```

Google and SO turned up a couple of posts implying that the code isn't ported to django 3.0...but the code IS django 3.0, so deep in django that it's kinda odd that this glitch took so long to show itself.

Settings and apache config checks OK. Database appears OK.
I'm stuck. Any/all ideas greatly appreciated.

Edit: Removing djangocms-blog restored operation to normal, with menus. Still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The django-parler package, a djangocms-blog dependency, was calling from_db_value() in djangocms_text_ckeditor/fields.py. from_db_value(), which overrides the function in djangodb.models.TextField, I think, has an argument "context" that is deprecated in django 3.0. Parler correctly calls the function without "context", which threw the exception. Removing the argument from from_db_value() (which it wasn't even using) appears to have eliminated the problem.

Edit: Known problem and corrected per the ckeditor git page, just not pushed out to pip yet. Grrr.